# Invalid use of Null in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm new to access and VBA and I am trying to test if a string value from my combo box is null or not however it keeps throwing an Invalid use of null error. I have a combobox and I want to check a column in the combobox to see if it exists. I have tried to use `IsNull()`, `var=null` and `var = ""` but all throw the same error.

my code:

```
Dim var As String
var = Me.CARS.Column(1)
If var = vbNullString Then
MsgBox "Yes"
End If
```

Comment: Combobox first column is ``var = Me.CARS.Column(0)``

Comment: As explained there, if you declare something as a string, it cannot be set to `Null`. `var` should be a variant. Also, `vbNullString` is a zero-length string, which is something entirely different from `Null`. `IsNull` is the right approach to check for null values.

Comment: The Nz ( variant [, valueifnull ] ) function could be of use here as well.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/nz-function-8ef85549-cc9c-438b-860a-7fd9f4c69b6c

Comment: If you want the value of combobox, don't need the Column property, just `Me.CARS`. From what you posted, the variable isn't even necessary. `If IsNull(Me.CARS) Then`.